# arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management ERROR 000840 after publishing?

Tags: arcpy, error-000840

I have a exception in arcpy script.In my code I can get  result  of Trace  on  geometic network as group layer..next  I want  to  extract only points  and return  those  values  as FetureLayer .So  I must to  create a Featureclass and  insert the  results of trace  in to it, this  work  for me  on ArcMap but When I publish it on Arcgis Server   I  get  this  error

```
in CreateFeatureclass raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Workspace. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Feature Dataset. Failed to execute (CreateFeatureclass).
```

and  it is  my code

```
FC =arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory","M12","POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED",spatial_reference)
 arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "TableName", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
 arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "Obj_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
 arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "GeoJson", "TEXT", "", "", "880", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
 arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "LayerId", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
 arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "LayerName", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Comment: The error is saying that its not a workspace and not a feature dataset. This means you need to identify the full path for both workspace and dataset,

Answer (score 1):

Replace `FeatureClass` in your AddField with "in_memory\M12". `FC` is a result object, so not the actual path to a FeatureClass. If you want to assign the full path to a variable I would have done the following:

```
resObj = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory","M12","POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED",spatial_reference)
FC = resObj.getOutput(0)
```